# Python package installation error for openCV

Tags: python, opencv

> C:\Users\Om>pip install opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
>
> Requirement 'opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
>
> Processing c:\users\om\opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
>
> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
>
> File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
>       ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
>
> File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
>       session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
>
> File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
>       unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
>
> File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
>       unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
>
> File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
>       flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
>
> File "c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 482, in unzip_file
>       zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Om\opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl'

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not given a valid file location.

The error is saying that it thinks you have given it a `whl` file to install but it can't find it.

I suggest you check you file path again.

Make sure it is located at `C:\Users\Om` and it is called exactly the same as the filename you have put down.  It should match `opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` **exactly**.

Ensure you do not rename the `whl` file.

Correct that and it will attempt an install and if that does not work you will get another error.